# Removing a message queue completely

Tags: php, queue, posix

I have a message queue in PHP which I use to process tasks, I caused a bug when inserting tasks and it has just inserted a bunch of bools (I usually pass objects through it).

I killed the process which reads the queue because it hung due to items not being removed.

My typical code which has worked fine for quite some time is:

```
    $mqst = msg_stat_queue($mqh);

    while ($mqst['msg_qnum']) {
        output('Queue is populated', O_DEBUG);
        msg_receive($mqh, 0, $msgtype, 2048, $data, true);
        $mqst = msg_stat_queue($mqh);
        if ($data instanceof \Core\Image) {
            $new_tasks[] = $data;
        } else {
            output('Got some odd data.. ' . print_r($data, true), O_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

From my terminal:

```
$ php -r '$mqh = msg_get_queue(12345, 0666);
          $mqst = msg_stat_queue($mqh); 
          $i = $mqst["msg_qnum"]; while ($i--) {
             msg_receive($mqh, 0, $type, 2048, $data, true);
             var_dump($type, $data); 
          }'
```

Output:

```
int(0)
bool(false)
int(0)
bool(false)
int(0)
bool(false)
int(0)
bool(false)
int(0)
bool(false)
int(0)
bool(false)
int(0)
bool(false)
```

I can repeat this indefinitely, they aren't budging. I've tried to just remove the queue but to no success, the documentation states:

> msg_remove_queue() destroys the message queue specified by the queue. Only use this function when all processes have finished working with the message queue and you need to release the system resources held by it.

However, I've killed the process and it isn't very specific on releasing the resources. I'm not sure why the messages aren't being popped off the queue after I receive them. Perhaps I'm missing something simple

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**EDIT** This answer was wrong.

After studying the question more thoroughly, I think the following is the problem: the first message in the queue is larger than 2048 byes, which causes `msg_receive` to return an error. Because of this, the message is never removed from the queue, so it will stay intact.

On next calls to the function, it will try to get the same entry, so it will fail again.

My initial suggestion to make the `msg_receive` function the condition of the while loop *would* have made this clear immediately. (if it is indeed the solution).

**Solution**: For now, add the `MSG_NOERROR` flag to the `msg_receive` function, just to see if the next message is indeed too large, and debug from there.

Comment: $i-- return previous value of $i (and then decrement) So, when it will be 0, it will be casted to false and stop

Comment: Nope, it wil not return the value of $i, it will just say: "ok, done that, what's next?" EDIT: Sorry, misunderstood what you were saying: yes it does. However while does not seem to break on 0 on my installation.

Comment: Read the manual. btw, I don't see while($i--) in the code now

Comment: Updated post. Thanks. And: it's in the code run in the terminal.

Comment: Sorry but this isn't the issue - when calling msg_receive the item should be removed from the queue, it isn't. There's no logic error.

Comment: Hmm, I understand. The output you posted is from the terminal, right?

Comment: Yes, the var_dump output is from the terminal. It was just a way to simulate what happens in the script to see what's in the queue.

Comment: @RiaD just looked through my "wall of shame" for obvious mistakes I should not make again, this one is on there. The only difference is the type in that case was a float, so it never hit "exactly zero". For some reason I have remembered this as: it doesn't work. My answer can be removed.

Comment: @Martin how big is `$i` when you first enter the loop?

Comment: 7, which is why there's 7 dumps :) --- But the loop/logic isn't the issue... It's the fact the queue is constantly populated with those items, it shouldn't be.

Comment: The reason to ask is because the values look very much like 'un-updated' values, as in: when the function called just flips out and returns false. Can you check if there is an error, by setting the last parameter in the `msg_receive` function? That would explain why the queue itself isn't updated: the `msg_receive` doesn't get through.

Comment: This could happen if the messages in the queue are larger than the 2048 byte size you've set, for example. **edit** or even if just the first message is bigger.

Comment: @Martin you could also try to set the `MSG_NOERROR` flag, this might give you more information immediately, removing the need for another debug round.

Comment: @creativedutchmen There was a message > 2048 bytes, you're right - thanks!

Comment: No problem: my apologies for being completely off-track at first. Glad you fixed it!